# Does Acumatica's OData layer support $count or $inlinecount

Tags: acumatica

When paginating data from an OData service in Acumatica, it would be preferable to have access to the total row count retrievable

These are OData services exposed via Generic Inquiries in Acumatica

The OData "Standard" suggests alternative ways to do this, e.g. via the $count directive, or via the $inlinecount parameter - both of which give errors via Acumatica

Examples:

http://localhost/acumatica2018r2/OData/$count/SomeGI

http://localhost/acumatica2018r2/OData/SomeGI?$inlinecount=allpages

Both of which give errors

$count: 
 "Message": "The OData path is invalid.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Invalid action detected. '$count' is not an action that can bind to 'Collection([PX.Data.CEN-Centara Stores Nullable=False])'.",

$inlinecount:
"message": "Query option 'InlineCount' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.",

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica's REST API supports only the following parameters:

> $filter $top $skip $expand $select $custom

You can find more details about Acumatica's REST API by this [link](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1c767ad9-da6d-4047-bc93-6970ad469504)